# How to pass color resource as parameter (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, background-color

This could be the simplest thing ever but for the life of me I haven't figured it out just yet.

I have a method that sets the background color of layout but I want to pass the color as a parameter like we do with drawable resources. eg

```
public void setIcon (Drawable icon){
  this.icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(icon);
}

setIcon(R.drawable.tuborg);
```

I want to be able to do something similar with `color (R.color.id)`. I've tried

```
public void setColor (Color color){
  layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(color));
}
```

and

```
public void setColor (Color color){
  layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(color));
}
```

both of which are asking for int, even `(int color)` doesn't work. Plus I'm trying to avoid Color.parse().

This is how I'm using the function

```
setColor(R.color.colorAccent);
```

I have an xml with various color codes. I want to be able just call this function and get the background color change.

Comment: public void setColor(int color) {
layout.setBackgroudColor(color);
}

Comment: thanks @Bhavnik but this does't work. I stated that in the question...

Comment: You are assigning value to layout.setBackgroundColor, instead of that setting color directly is not working ??

Comment: you are almost there. you don't need `Color` - colors are actually represented as `int` (notice that getColor returns an int and setBackgroundColor takes an int), but what may be confusing is how `getColor` also takes an int as a parameter - its expecting the resource ID of the color defined in xml. So you can simply pass the resourceID and use `getColor` on it, OR, you can pass the color itself (as an int) and use `setBackgroundColor` on it directly.

Comment: so how do i pass that in a function @trooper

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. Finally got it work. All your answers and suggestions where interesting but i went with the one that was closest to my usecase. Thanks a bunch..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
public void setColor (int colorId){
  layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(colorId));
}
```

In that method colorId should be an hexa code of the color

A good practice is to define the color on colors.xml (inside values folder).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

In this case, you will use this function like this:

```
setColor(R.color.red);
```

So, there is no need to create a "color" object, you can pass values from colors.xml

Also, in your case you should modify the method setColor(Color aColor) to **setColor(int aColor)** to make it work with the xml color resource.

Comment: Doesnt work, expects a resource of type color. Yes i have the xml. That's what i'm trying to reference

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi are you referencing by doing this R.color.your_color_in_colors_xml?
Could you tell me which is the class of "layout"?

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi I have edited my answer with this: Also, in your case you should modify the method setColor(Color aColor) to setColor(int aColor) to make it work with the xml color resource.

Comment: I think `ContextCompat.getColor(colorId)` needs a context so it may be like this `ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, colorId)`

Answer (score 8):

You need a color resource id. It starts with **R.color** which is actually an **integer id**.

```
public void setColor (@ColorInt int colorId){ // integer id 
  layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(colorId));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Although you are using it like `setColor(R.color.colorAccent)` but still your **function parameter** expects a `color` e.g.

> setColor (**Color** color)

. You need to update the function parameter type to `int`, like I did in the above snippet.

> setColor (**int** color)

Also from the docs of `ContextCompat.getColor`.

> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID.Starting in
>   {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#M}, the returned color will be
>   styled for the specified Context's theme.
>
> @param id The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt
>   tool.  This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry. The
>   value 0 is an invalid identifier.
>
> @return A single color value in the form 0xAARRGGBB.

Answer (score 3):

For one, it looks like you're trying to set properties of the `View` which is not a concept that exists in Java.  So what you really want is:

`layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRes));`

`View#setBackgroundColor()` expects a color integer in the format `#AARRGGBB` in which

A = alpha
R = red
G = green
B = blue.

So to set the color pure red you can do something like this:

`layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);`

Pure blue:

`layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);`

Pure green:

`layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);`

For [Resources#getColor(int);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)), it is expect a Resource ID of the color you want.  In this case, you would put `colors.xml` in the `res/values` folder of your project.  Then have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can retrieve the color like so:

```
int color = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Or if you're on API 23 or higher:

```
int color = context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Or the more simple `ContextCompat` method:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Then you can set the background color with it like so:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

And finally, if you don't want to do any of that, you can simply set it directly on the View like so:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Comment: so there's really no way to append R.color.id to context.getResources().getColor(R.id.colorRes);

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi Not sure what you mean by that.  The `R.id` is a resource ID.  It doesn't mean anything beyond that.  It's only meant to link to the resource.  Also, I messed up.  It's supposed to be `R.color.` since it's a color resource.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi: I've edited the answer quite a bit.  Hopefully you'll find something in there that helps.